# Using a Surface in MediaPlayer after it has been manually drawn on

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview, surface

I have a SurfaceView that I use as Display for MediaPlayer. I also need to alternatively draw on the same Surface manually by locking/unlocking the Canvas. This never happens at the same time though!

The problem is that as soon I have once locked and unlocked the Surface, it will be unusable for MediaPlayer. The other way round is no problem. I can play a video on the Surface, reset the player and then manually draw on the Surface as I like.

This works:

1. Play a video on the Surface using MediaPlayer.
2. Reset MediaPlayer and draw on the surface manually by locking/unlocking the canvas.

This fails:

1. Lock the surface, draw on it, and unlock it again.
2. Play a video on the Surface with MediaPlayer.

It will fail with an **IllegalStateException** when **MediaPlayer.prepare()** is called. Strangely, the message of the exception is "**null**".

The same happens with a Surface that is used in a SurfaceTexture (e.g. in a GL context).

**I wonder what happens with the Surface after locking/unlocking it, that MediaPlayer does not like it anymore.**

I might need to end up using multiple Surfaces and switching between them. But I'd like to avoid that since I have a setup with a mix of multiple SurfaceViews and also GlSurfaceViews using SurfaceTextures.

Here is some code to reproduce the phenomenon. Make sure that VIDEO_FILE points to a valid video.

**MainActivity.java:**

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Make sure this points to a valid video
    private String VIDEO_FILE = "/sdcard/Movies/some-video.mp4";

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Button playButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    private Button drawButton;
    private boolean alternate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.video_surfaceview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        drawButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.draw_button);

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                // Make sure we only do things when surface is ready
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                drawButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            }
        });

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(VIDEO_FILE);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Main", "Play failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
        });

        drawButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Surface surface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                // Toggle between green and red
                if (alternate) {
                    canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
                }
                alternate = !alternate;
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**layout/main_activity.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/video_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Play"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Stop"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/draw_button"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Draw"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

There is three buttons: "Play", "Stop", "Draw". You may press "Play" and "Stop" several times (which should work as expected). Then press "Draw" multiple times (this should draw alternating red and green). Now press "Play" again (this will fail).

If you start with "Draw" in the beginning, then "Play" will never work.

Make sure to press "Stop" before pressing "Draw" when a video is playing. Otherwise it will crash (for a valid reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just was wondering whether I should be proud of that Tumbleweed badge that I got for this question and decided to do one last research on that topic. The first thing I then stumbled across was this architecture documentation about Surface and SurfaceHolder:

https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sh

It's funny, because it seems to contain the exact answer of my question:

> When you lock a Surface for Canvas access, the "CPU renderer" connects
>   to the producer side of the BufferQueue and does not disconnect until
>   the Surface is destroyed. Most other producers (like GLES) can be
>   disconnected and reconnected to a Surface, but the Canvas-based "CPU
>   renderer" cannot. This means you can't draw on a surface with GLES or
>   send it frames from a video decoder if you've ever locked it for a
>   Canvas.

Meanwhile I have implemented a solution with multiple surfaces anyhow. I suppose I will now stick to it.

Thanks for listening.